# How do I update an angularjs page after a scope update?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have written a directive that captures keyboard events, and on certain keys I update some objects in the scope. The idea is to move up and down an array and display the selected row details. The problem is the page is not updated until I do another action that updates the page. How can I force this?

Here's the directive:

```
LogApp.directive("keyCapture", [function(){
    var scopeInit;
    return{
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
            scopeInit = scope
            element.on('keydown', function(e){
                scopeInit[attrs.keyCapture].apply(null, [e]);                
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Bound the template like this:

```
<body ng-controller="logCtrl" key-capture="movePreview">
```

The controller method:

```
$scope.movePreview = function(e){
    if ($scope.events.length === 0)
        return;
    // Find the element 
    if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40){
        console.log("Pressed %s", e.keyCode);
        var offset = 0;
        if (e.keyCode === 38 && $scope.previewIndex > 0)
            offset = -1;
        else if (e.keyCode === 40 && $scope.previewIndex < $scope.events.length -1 )
            offset = 1;

        $scope.previewIndex += offset;
        var eventId = $scope.events[$scope.previewIndex].uuid;
        $scope.showEvent(eventId);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

`$scope.showEvent(eventId)` will take the item with given ID and display it in another part of the page. Part that is not update until another action is performed, like clicking a button. Is it possible to force the page update?

Here's a fiddle that reproduces: http://jsfiddle.net/gM2KF/1/
If you click on the button, the counter is updated. If you press any key, nothing shows. But you click again on the button, you see the counter has been updated by the keyboard event, but didn't show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are listening to non-angular events:

```
element.on('keydown', function(e){
    scopeInit[attrs.keyCapture].apply(null, [e]);                
});
```

Then, to update the scope, you need to call `scope.$apply`:

```
element.on('keydown', function(e){
    scopeInit[attrs.keyCapture].apply(null, [e]); 
    scope.$apply();               
});
```

This will kick off an angular `$digest` cycle and allow changes to bind.

Comment: What's the best practice: call  `scope.$apply()` after the change, or as m59 suggests, wrap the code in the $apply? What's the difference?

Comment: @Antoine better to wrap part of code with `scope.$apply(function(){/**/}` than just call `scope.$apply();` to invoke diggest cycle for only part of code

Comment: Hmm, apologies, by the way... I would have just commented on your answer, but there were no answers showing at the time. I've never seen SO do that before..

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the `$scope` changes in `$scope.$apply();`

While your code could be altogether cleaner, this ought to make it work:

```
$scope.movePreview = function(e){
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    if ($scope.events.length === 0)
        return;
    // Find the element 
    if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40){
        console.log("Pressed %s", e.keyCode);
        var offset = 0;
        if (e.keyCode === 38 && $scope.previewIndex > 0)
            offset = -1;
        else if (e.keyCode === 40 && $scope.previewIndex < $scope.events.length -1 )
            offset = 1;

        $scope.previewIndex += offset;
        var eventId = $scope.events[$scope.previewIndex].uuid;
        $scope.showEvent(eventId);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a single example that prints out events based on your example:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl" key-capture  move="movePreview()">    
    <pre>Pressed: {{previewIndex}}</pre>    
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {   
    $scope.movePreview = function(e){        
        $scope.previewIndex = e.keyCode; 
};

}
app.$inject = ['$scope'];
app.directive("keyCapture", [function(){
    var scopeInit;
    return{
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){

             element.bind('keydown', function (e) {
                scope.$apply(function(){scope.movePreview(e);});                    
            });            
        }
    }
}]);
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbcpq/16/)**</kbd>

We call `movePreview` method on each key event.